# Kill snowflake query after UI timeout (PHP)

Tags: php, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, backend, kill

A UI timeout is happening in 65 seconds, and the long query keeps running in Snowflake. Once UI hits the timeout, I want to kill all these running queries from PHP backend code.

Is there any way to achieve this from the PHP backend code?
What I can think of is to use PHP `$_SESSION` but didn't get any lead on googling.

I have PHP API with all the required snowflake connections and query-related code.

**Note** Can't use `STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS` function of Snowflake since I only want to abort those queries which go through UI and then UI gets timeout before the query completes execution.

Comment: What exactly is the question, what do you need help with?

Comment: Updated the question for better understanding @Sergiu

Comment: Can you define "UI timeout"? Do you mean that the request to the backend server times out? What would the point be to have those long running queries if you want to abort them before they are finished? Wouldn't that always be the case then?

Comment: UI timeout here means that after 65sec if the query does not complete, the UI will throw a message pop-up saying "data is large. Please contact support team" instead of waiting to complete the query and showing data. Since there is a timeout and I know data is not going to come to UI now, I want to abort such queries from snowflake.  @M.Eriksson

Comment: The safest way would be to call the system function [SYSTEM$CANCEL_QUERY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_cancel_query) but you need to catch first the query id of the long running query.